# Different colors and labels for overlapping areas

Tags: geoserver, wms, labeling, overlapping-features

I am using Geoserver 2.9.2 + WMS and I need to apply the following for a single layer:

1. make overlapping polygon areas have a distinct color and
2. have those overlapping areas labeled (centered of course) with unique labels?

Comment: You probably need to run a WPS to do the intersection and labelling

Answer (score 1):

SLD has no currently no way to control cross-layer interactions.

So, you either:

- Pre-process the data, computing the intersections in advance
- Do it on the fly building your own custom "rendering transformation" in Java code, which entails creating a WPS Process and then calling it from SLD, see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html